# WPF: Formatting a label

Tags: wpf, fonts, resourcedictionary

I have the following code for an Expander:

```
   <Expander Name="CompanyLinks" Header="{StaticResource companyLinksHeader}"
              FontSize="18" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemSummary}" 
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemInfo}" 
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemIssues}" 
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemMessages}" 
                   FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>   
    </Expander>
```

The StaticResources are defined as follows (in my resource dictionary):

```
<sys:String x:Key="companyLinksHeader">company</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="companyLinksItemSummary">summary</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="companyLinksItemInfo">info</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="companyLinksItemIssues">issues</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="companyLinksItemMessages">messages</sys:String>
```

Is there a way to define a dictionary entry (or something else) that will handle the Font styling for the Header and Labels so that I don't have to define the same font over and over (and only change it in one place should I want to change the font)?

**EDIT**

I found a solution (thanks to those that posted) and am using the following Style for the StackPanel Label items:

```
<!-- Expander Items text style -->
<Style x:Key="expanderItemsTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontWeight" Value="Normal"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
</Style>
```

and implementing it like this (applying it to the StackPanel so it affects all Labels):

```
<Expander Name="CompanyLinks" Header="{StaticResource companyLinksHeader}"
          Style="{StaticResource expanderHeaderTextStyle}">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource expanderItemsTextStyle}">
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemSummary}"/>
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemInfo}" />
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemIssues}" />
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemMessages}" />
    </StackPanel>   
</Expander>
```

One thing that does not work though is the Label.Foreground.  The foreground color remains black but I can change the font, size or weight via the style.  If I move the style into the Label definition though the color works.  Is this a bug or is there a different property that will set the font color (foreground) of the StackPanel Labels.

Comment: You can create a common style and apply it to the labels.

Comment: Thank you.  Was searching for label formatting and not styling.  Found the answer once I searched for style.

Comment: @BrianKE updated to include StackPanel

Comment: Also found a similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877515/set-style-for-all-textblocks-in-a-stack-panel

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a `Style` within `Window.Resources`, and refer to this style using [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) within the `StackPanel.Resources` section. This will apply the styles to all labels inside that `StackPanel`.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
         </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Expander Name="CompanyLinks" Header="{StaticResource companyLinksHeader}"
              FontSize="18" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource myLabelStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemSummary}" />
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemInfo}" />
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemIssues}" />
            <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemMessages}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a Style:

```
<Expander Name="CompanyLinks" Header="{StaticResource companyLinksHeader}"
          FontSize="18" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Expander.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Style>
    </Expander.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemSummary}" />
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemInfo}" />
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemIssues}" />
        <Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemMessages}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Here the `Style` targets all `Label` within `Expander`.

Comment: Marked this one as correct as it is as close to what I wanted.  However I did have a question about applying the style to the StackPanel (please see the original question edit)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Fontsize and Font Name in the Resource file

```
<FontFamily x:Key="BaseFontFamily">Calibri</FontFamily>
<sys:Double x:Key="BaseFontSize">12</sys:Double>


<Label Content="{StaticResource companyLinksItemMessages}" 
      FontSize="{StaticResource BaseFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource fntfam}"/>
```