# How to set Padding="0" for all TextBox controls in one form?

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to set the Attribute `Padding="0"` globally for all TextBox controls in a WPF form?

I found this article:
[Set style for all textblocks in a stack panel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4877515/2504785)

But I don't want to repeat the setting for each StackPanel. I just want to set it once globally for the whole form. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a style in the resources of your XAML.

If you create a key for the style, you will need to write Style={} for each TextBox.  If you don't create the style key, it will apply everywhere anyway!

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}" Text="Hi"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Or, if you want every TextBox to be affected:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="Hi"/>
</StackPanel>
```