# Making all images be of the same size and margin

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I noticed that I've got a few images in a stack panel and every such has **exactly** the same size, margin, alignment etc. set to it. I don't want to create a global resource for style. Is it possible to have a local style declared in **this specific** panel and only for the images (*TargetType* is enough in this case)?

I'd like something along [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877559/1525840) with the exception that I don't use the global style resource.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
    ...
  </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<Image Source="{StaticResource Poof}"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         ...
         Margin="20,20,20,0" />
```

Comment: in your code, the style isn't global but control level(stackPanel), what improvement do you seek ?

Comment: @Nikita For some reason (not know to me at the moment of writing), that property doesn't affect the appearance of the image. I've removed the settings from the image itself but the style still doesn't seem to be seen by the control. Naturally, I assumed that I've done something wrong, although trying to follow the example linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the style in the resources for the panel, and it will apply to all items of that type, inside the panel.

For example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox  Margin="20" />
    <TextBox  Margin="20" />
    <TextBox  Margin="20" />
    <TextBox  Margin="20" />
</StackPanel>
```

Results in all the text boxes having a width of 200 units.

Unless, you override the style with a setting on the individual items. Perhaps you are doing that?

Comment: So I thought too. But it seems that it just doesn't get effective. Perhaps I'm missing something... Please see the addition to my question in a minute.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've edited my answer to include code which I have just tested and know to work. Based on what you have provided I can only guess as to what the problem might be, but the concept works.

Answer (score 1):

Try add style inside resources.

```
    <Page.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
            </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
```