# Apply same dynamic style to all elements of same kind in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, styling, dynamicresource

I have a Grid full of Labels that all use the same style which is a DynamicResource:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}"/>
```

Is there a way to only set the style once for all labels in the grid? I tried it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877559/2102827), however `BasedOn` doesn't work with `DynamicResources`.

Comment: Include the dictionary in your `UC` or `Window` then refer to it as a `StaticResource`, or set the Style for Label like so `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">..code</Style>`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX: You mean the MergedDictionary from my App.xaml? How do I put that in my UC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `MergedDictionaries` like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/assemblyName;component/yourStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--If you want to include additional resources you need to place them here-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in your Grid you can use it like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources><!-- This will only use the style in the Grid-->
        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

And this should now use your Style only for the Grid or a `Label` where `Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"`.

Comment: This works. Also it seems that it's sufficient to have the MergedDictionary in the App.xaml instead of the UserControl. Does that have any side effects?

Comment: @gartenriese To be honest I never tried that and from what I can tell your exe and your UC's are in a separate assembly. What VS are you using?

Comment: I'm using styles from a different assembly, however the App.xaml and the UserControl is in the same project. I'm using VS2013.

Comment: There you go, if your `UC`'s were in a different assembly then the `exe` then it wouldn't work. About including styles from different assemblies, it doesn't make any difference as the WPF uses URI and you can just refer to an assembly in there, like I pointed in my answer. @gartenriese

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Label">

    ...

    </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: What do I put in place of the three dots?

Comment: The style you did in "MyStyle".

Comment: The style is in another assembly.